# Appendix page, appendix in TOC and appendix page numbering

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering, appendices, appendix

I'm currently writing my thesis and I have the following rules to obey by in the way I present my appendix:

1. In the TOC the "Appendix" word should appear in the beginning of an appendix chapter entry.
2. There should be a \appendixpage separating references from appendices. This page should be unnumbered and preferably appear in the TOC without any number as well.
3. The page numbering in the appendices should be A1, A2, etc.

Bellow goes an example of what I've tried to do so far:

```
\documentclass[10pt, twoside, openright, dvipsnames]{report}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand{\chaptername}{}
\renewcommand{\appendixname}{Appendix }
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\normalfont\scshape\LARGE\color{MidnightBlue}}{\chaptertitlename\thechapter\hspace{0pt}\color{MidnightBlue}\hspace{10pt}}{0pt}{\LARGE}

\titleformat*{\section}{\normalfont\scshape\Large\color{MidnightBlue}}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalfont\scshape\large\color{MidnightBlue}}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\normalfont\scshape\normalsize\color{MidnightBlue}}


\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\myappendixpage}{%
  \begingroup
  \let\ps@plain\ps@empty
  \appendixpage
  \endgroup}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Intro}
\chapter{Development}
\section{Intro}


\appendix
\myappendixpage
\noappendicestocpagenum
\addappheadtotoc

\chapter{One}
\pagenumbering{arabic}    
\renewcommand*{\thepage}{A\arabic{page}}
\lipsum[1-2]
\chapter{Two}
\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

This code has several problems:

1. The page number in page number 5 is missing for some reason.
2. The word "Appendix" does not appear in the TOC before the entries.
3. The appendixpage formatting (MidnightBlue color) is not coherent with the rest of the document.

Hope someone can shed light on this matter.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a modified version of your MWE (for which, thank you) that I hope does what you want. I'm colour blind so I don't do colours.

```
% appendixprob.tex SE 532681 various appendix problems

\documentclass[10pt, twoside, openright, dvipsnames]{report}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand{\chaptername}{}
\renewcommand{\appendixname}{Appendix }
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\normalfont\scshape\LARGE\color{MidnightBlue}}{\chaptertitlename\thechapter\hspace{0pt}\color{MidnightBlue}\hspace{10pt}}{0pt}{\LARGE}

\titleformat*{\section}{\normalfont\scshape\Large\color{MidnightBlue}}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalfont\scshape\large\color{MidnightBlue}}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\normalfont\scshape\normalsize\color{MidnightBlue}}


\usepackage[toc,page,title,titletoc]{appendix}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\myappendixpage}{%
  \begingroup
  \let\ps@plain\ps@empty
  \appendixpage
  \endgroup}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Intro}
\chapter{Development}
\section{Intro}


%\appendix
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\renewcommand*{\thepage}{A\arabic{page}}
\begin{appendices}
%\myappendixpage
%\noappendicestocpagenum
%\addappheadtotoc

\chapter{One}
%\pagenumbering{arabic}    
%\renewcommand*{\thepage}{A\arabic{page}}
\lipsum[1-2]
\chapter{Two}
\lipsum[1-2]
\newpage
\lipsum[3]
\newpage
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great work, almost there! The only thing that is left to do is make sure the appendices page starts openright and that the numbering starts on Appendix A and leaves "Appendices" page unnumbered. Thanks for the input.